# Difference between おかあさん and ははおや

Tags: word-choice, politeness, word-requests, word-usage, register

What is the difference between these two terms for the word «mother»?

- おかあさん
- ははおや

Is there a difference in politeness/register in addressing someone, our some other form of difference between these two?

My dictionary also lists:

- はは
- かあさん
- ははのみこと

as being in current usage.

Also, I cannot figure out why katakana, which is usually used for foreign words, would also be used for two forms of mother, as listed in my dictionary, as follows (please note, I couldn't get my input method on my Android keyboard to input the first of these in katakana as in the dictionary, perhaps someone can tell me how to do it).

- おもに
- ママン

REFERENCE:

[image: mother in Japanese dictionary]

Thanks.

Comment: Your dictionary app is using the edict dictionary as a source for its definitions, but is failing to display the 'archaic' and 'honorific' tags for ははのみこと and the source-language tag for オモニ。 I would strongly recommend getting a different application.

Comment: Furthermore, a full-blown dictionary for a beginner such as you is probably more confusing than it is worth. You should stick to the dumbed-down dictionary that your textbook provides for the time being, so that you will learn the more common words first.

Comment: (Also worth mentioning is that edict is a J-E dictionary. It fares poorly in the other direction.)

Comment: I believe that ママン comes from French: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/maman#French

Comment: You are right, Takoboto is based on the JMDict project. It also seems to be the highest rated app on Google Play. However, please note that I do not consider myself a complete beginner as I know some Chinese, and as such, I have a strong interest in learning about orthography, spelling, and kanji. And about conjugations since I know a few European languages as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I think the relationship between お母さん and 母親 is like that of *mom* and *mother*, in English.

Answer (score 5):

お母さん (okaasan) is the polite form of "mother". You use it to address your own mother or when talking about the mothers of other people.

母親 or just 母 (haha) is the plain form of "mother". You use it to be humble when talking about your own mother to other people, or when politeness is not necessary.

Comment: This always confused me, I was taught the way you wrote it here, but in reality, living in Japan, my experience is that people tend to use お母さん in almost all situations, except when talking to complete strangers...

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is that you can't use はは to talk about someone else's mother.   I think you must use お母さん in that case. Usually Japanese people call their mothers おかあさん when they talk to them directly. はは is used to talk about your mother to other people.

Answer (score 0):

You can translate お母さん and 母親 to *mother* and *mom*.

---

I have never heard オモニ and 母の命... オモニ is Korean.
And I hardly use ママン. It would be better if you used お母さん, 母親, or ママ.

## For example:

> - お母さんは[既]{すで}にお[婆]{ばあ}さんになった。 - My mother has become an old lady.
> - お母さんと[一緒]{いっしょ} - My mother and I together.
>
>   - There is a TV program called [おかあさんといっしょ](http://www.nhk.or.jp/kids/program/okaasan.html) in Japan.

Comment: Interesting. In といっしょ(と一緒) must mean と=with+一緒=together, meaning together. But with and together must mean the same thing, so we have a repetition of the same word. Is my analysis correct? Does it happen often in Japanese to have two words together that mean the same thing to mean the same thing (like in Chinese two characters meaning the same thing mean that thing)?

Comment: Is there a spelling in your answer? Did you mean to write that ははのみこと (母のみこと) is Korean? Thanks.

Comment: @JackMaddington I probably think `母のみこと` isn't korean. `母のみこと` is wrong.

Comment: But ははのみこと is Korean, and can also be spelled はは命, correct? Not sure how a word from Korean made its way to being represented with a Kanji. Must be Ateji, correct?

Comment: Anyways, when I type hahaninikoto on my Swype keyboard, the keyboard also suggests 母のみこと。Not sure what that is, but it must be something. I doubt my keyboard's autosuggest feature is wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @JackMaddington If Its readings is ははのいのち, It is OK. but It 母の[命]{いのち} means My mother's life.